# How to group by multiple object elements

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have sample data like below

```
[
    {
        brand:"iphone",
        category:"mobile"
    },
    {
        brand:"iphone",
        category:"laptop"
    },
    {
        brand:"lenova",
        category:"laptop"   
    }
]
```

and expecting result as

```
[
    {
        brand:"iphone",
        count:2
    },
    {
        brand:"lenova",
        count:1
    },
    {
        category:"laptop",
        count:2
    },
    {
        category:"mobile",
        count:1
    }
]
```

Here I want group by same object with multiple fields and get there count. Can any one please let me how to do that in the mongoose.

Comment: This is definitely not possible with single query, it will take two aggregations.
If you want to groupBy two fields combined that is possible in single query.

Comment: can you tell me with two aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiarised with Mongoose. Just tried in Mongoshell

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
  { 
    $group:{
        _id:"$brand",
        brand:{$first:"$brand"},
        category:{$first:"$category"}

     }    
  },
  {$project:{_id:0}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible only by using two queries.

> 1. Group By Brand

```
db.getCollection('pages').aggregate([   
    {
      $group: {_id: "$brand", category: { $push: "$category" }} 
    },
    {
      $project : {
        _id : 0, brand : "$_id", count : {$size : "$category"}
      }
    },
    { $unwind: { path: "$category", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } }
])
```

**Result**:-

```
/* 1 */
{
    "brand" : "lenova",
    "count" : 1
}

/* 2 */
{
    "brand" : "iphone",
    "count" : 2
}
```

> 2. Group By Category

```
db.getCollection('pages').aggregate([  
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$category", brand: { $push: "$brand" },
        }
    },
    {
        $project : {
            _id : 0, category : "$_id", count : {$size : "$brand"}
        }
    },
    { $unwind: { path: "$brand", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
])
```

**Result:-**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "category" : "laptop",
    "count" : 2
}

/* 2 */
{
    "category" : "mobile",
    "count" : 1
}
```

Merge them for the required output.

Answer (score 0):

We can use **[$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)** to run parallel aggregation on data.

**The following query can get us the expected output:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet:{
      "brand_group":[
        {
          $group:{
            "_id":"$brand",
            "brand":{
              $first:"$brand"
            },
            "count":{
              $sum:1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project:{
            "_id":0
          }
        }
      ],
      "category_group":[
        {
          $group:{
            "_id":"$category",
            "category":{
              $first:"$category"
            },
            "count":{
              $sum:1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project:{
            "_id":0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project:{ 
      "array":{
        $concatArrays:["$brand_group","$category_group"]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind:"$array"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot:{ 
      "newRoot":"$array"
    }
  }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5da5c0d0795c8651a7f508c2"),
  "brand" : "iphone",
  "category" : "mobile"
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5da5c0d0795c8651a7f508c3"),
  "brand" : "iphone",
  "category" : "laptop"
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5da5c0d0795c8651a7f508c4"),
  "brand" : "lenova",
  "category" : "laptop"
}
```

**Output:**

```
{ "brand" : "lenova", "count" : 1 }
{ "brand" : "iphone", "count" : 2 }
{ "category" : "laptop", "count" : 2 }
{ "category" : "mobile", "count" : 1 }
```